# What minhag is this tefillin wrapping in this video?

Tags: minhag, tefilin, chabad, arizal

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLDXtjBbNuU) on YouTube shows  man showing a particular minhag for wrapping tefillin which he says is Nusach Arizal. It looks a lot like the Chabad method (such as making the shin on the bicep), but I noticed he uses regular Chasidic tefillin (with the Sephardi kesher on the shel yad).

Is he just showing you how to do the Chabad method with regular Sfard tefillin, or what? Additionally, what's the minhag he wraps on his hand?

Comment: I couldn't listen with sound but while similar to chabad the shin is not in exactly the same place. As for the hand. Since the shin is already closer up on the arm then the hand has a daled and a yud spelling out shin then a daled and then a yud